# How to make custom module for Scilab?

Tags: scilab

I have to custom module for Scilab. After reading of documentation, I try to use toolbox_skeleton, but I don't know how I can load this module into Scilab: I press "load", select "loader" of module from "contrib" folder, and type c_sum(3,5) into window of Scilab - then I will get error "Unknown variable c_sum". Where have I made a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

The normal step:

call the builder.sce
and then the loader.sce